# CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0 when loading grayscaled image

Tags: ios, xcode, quartz-graphics

i m using xcode and would like to load a grayscale image into the program but i am having problem with it.

Previously i have converted a grayscaled IplImage(size,8, 1) to UIimage and stored as an jpg. Now i would like to revert the process to get back the IplImage.

I obtain UIimage by doing

```
UIImage *uiimage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1.JPG"];
```

Then i use the following function.

```
- (IplImage *)CreateIplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
// Getting CGImage from UIImage
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
// Creating temporal IplImage for drawing
IplImage *iplimage = cvCreateImage(
                                   cvSize(image.size.width,image.size.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4
                                   );
// Creating CGContext for temporal IplImage
CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                iplimage->imageData, iplimage->width, iplimage->height,
                                                iplimage->depth, iplimage->widthStep,
                                                colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault
                                                );
// Drawing CGImage to CGContext
CGContextDrawImage(
                   contextRef,
                   CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height),
                   imageRef
                   );
CGContextRelease(contextRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

// Creating result IplImage
IplImage *ret = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iplimage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvCvtColor(iplimage, ret, CV_RGBA2BGR);
cvReleaseImage(&iplimage);

return ret;
```

}

This works fine for loading color image with the standard RGBA channels, but i have some problem when i want to load grayscale image with only 1 channel and no alpha channel.

i have tried to change colorSpace to CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), change the number of channels from 4 to 1 and commented out the cvCvtColor and return IplImage *iplimage directly

however, i still have the error, CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0

I think there might be a problem with CGBitmapContextCreate and likely something wrong with bitmapInfo..

i tried a few combinations such as kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault|kCGImageAlphaNone but none of them work.

Any idea how what i should do please? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look into **CGBitmapContextCreate**'s documentation. (in xCode CMD + right click I think to see documentation)

Did u set size_t bytesPerRow for that cases? RGBA is 8+8+8+8 bit long, only Alpha is 8

CGContextRef CGBitmapContextCreate ( void *data, size_t width, size_t height, size_t bitsPerComponent, size_t bytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceRef space, CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo );